# PC-Lint: Ignore Library errors

Tags: c, pc-lint

I'm using PC-Lint to lint a C project. I want to ignore errors and warnings in third party libraries, but I'm not able to get this. Reading the manual, I check all #include files specified with angle brackets are considered as libraries.

> [...] and you want this header to be regarded as a library header use angle brackets
>   as in: #include <\include\graph.h>

Or for example, using the -libh command to indicate that header file is a library.

Using the option -vf, I've verified that my library files are being included as libraries. So everithing is OK.

The problems is that I'm receiving lot of errors from these files. I thought that since these files are considered as libraries, errors would be ignored.

How can ignore errors in library files? I've tried with -wlib(0), but this option ignore errors in header files too. In addition, generates an umcofortable warning:

> Warning 686: Option '-wlib(0)' is suspicious because
>       of 'the likelihood of causing meaningless output'; receiving a syntax error
>       in a library file most likely means something is wrong with your Lint
>       confinguration

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are your normal headers also considered library files then, otherwise is wouldn't make much sense for -wlib(0) to exclude all messages from headers. And can you show a short example of your include and an error message you receive from PC-lint for one of the headers?

Comment: You were right. The problem is by default, the expression +libclass(angle, foreign) is always enabled. So all include files were being considered as library files. It is necessary to overwrite this expression by using +libclass(angle) in order to treat these files as headers and not libraries. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to read several times the PC-Lint manual and check the output log several times. The "problem" is by default the expression

> +libclass(angle, foreign)

is enabled, so all .h files are considered libraries. It is necessary to overwrite this expression by using:

+libclass(angle)

In order to treat these files as headers an not libraries.

Thanks again.

Comment: Are you still using `-wlib(0)` then? I don't enjoy that warning.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting late but I found this thread when looking for ways to remove the -wlib(0) warning in the output.

So for others looking for that answer a simple `-e686` before the `-wlib(0)` removes that warning from the output.

I understand this does not answer the original question, but sometimes this is what you want to do.